# HTML POST sometimes does not submit POST data to PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms, post

OK, this is a bit weird.

So I have many people who doing work online completing online forms. These forms are then POSTed back to the same page, which records the entry and then gives them a new entry to do.

The problem is that around 1/100 of the entries appears to go missing. According to my logs the PHP script thinks that these have been submitted with no POST data (like a page refresh). But many users of the site are having this problem.

I don't see how this could be an error in my code or in the HTML form as the code & HTML is basically the same for each page/entry.

I'm at my wits end trying to figure out where the problem is. I put very detailed logs on the PHP script, recording everything. According to those logs the missing entries are missing because there is no POST data (not even a `$_REQUEST['submit']` variable set), but the users are all adamant that they pressed the submit button and did not refresh the page.

Is this normal? Any way to fix it?

Form looks like this:

```
<form action="display.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="desc" cols="80" rows="20">'.$description.'</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="savepk" value="1"/>
<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="pibn" VALUE="3434"/>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="user" VALUE="12"/>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="what" VALUE="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="pk" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="go" value="0/>
<input type="hidden" name="debug" value="0"/>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" VALUE="Done (10)" ONCLICK="parent.Switch();" style="width:300;height:40px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#F2FF9E;"/>
</form>
```

The parent page including javascript is:

```
<HTML><HEAD><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">
<script type="text/javascript">
var on=0;
function Switch()
    {
    if (on==0)
        {
        on=1;
        document.getElementById("frame0").style.top="-1000";
        document.getElementById("frame1").style.top="0";
        }
    else
        {
        on=0;
        document.getElementById("frame1").style.top="-1000";
        document.getElementById("frame0").style.top="0";
        }
    }
</script>
</HEAD><BODY>
<iframe src="display.php" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0;" class="frame0" id="frame0"></iframe>
<iframe src="display.php" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:-1000;" class="frame1" id="frame1"></iframe>
</BODY></HTML>
```

That javascript is used to load 2 of the pages at a time and alternate them. Hence the `parent.Switch()` on the form onclick event. That works perfectly.

Comment: Does the HTML [validate](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: Provide some of the code

Answer (score -1):

With this little information, a wild guess would be that there is a JavaScript error (perhaps when validating the form) that causes a `location.href` or `location.reload()` event which leads to the page being reloaded with a GET request?

Comment: OK, the only bit of javascript on the page is quite simple and is doing the same thing each time. Could the javascript randomly not work sometimes?

Comment: Maybe the visitor has JavaScript turned off. What is your JavaScript doing?

Comment: They all have javascript. It's the same people doing the entries. The javascript is doing a preloader: it moves an iframe out of view and another into view.

Comment: Maybe you could post the Javascript code? And also confirm that these failing requests are indeed GET requests and not POST requests.

Comment: I think it is likely that the form is being opened without the frame or for some other reason the `parent` object is not accessible. This would result in a Javascript error and the page would reload with the form data getting lost. You could probably try to reproduce it by opening `display.php` directly.